# Configure application url using ASP.NET Web Api and OWIN

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api, owin

I know there are some similar questions but non of them helped me.
I have an project (ASP.NET Web Application .NET Framework). It is meant to be a service and i want to run it as a console application. 
I use OWIN(WebApp.Start call the Startup method) and have the next main method:

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var applicationUrl= "http://localhost:12345";
        using (WebApp.Start<Startup>(applicationUrl))
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"Application started at{applicationUrl}");
            Console.WriteLine("Press [enter] to quit...");
            Console.ReadLine();
        };
    }
```

Is there a way to put the application url somewhere in config folders so i can read it dynamicaly, so i can put this application on some real server?

Comment: Yes; it is absolutely possible to read files.  What have you tried? What don't you understand?

Comment: @SLaks I was wondering if there was some specific way to get the application configuration with OWIN? Sorry if i make no sense, i'm new to this stuff

Comment: Put it in web.config and use the configurationManager.AppSettings["KeyValue"] to set it to your var

Comment: @Verthosa thank you for answering. I can put it in web.config,no problem. But i was wondering if there is a way to get the app url without me having to create a setting so every time i deploy the service i have to update the web.config as well?